# Can I get 'until' parameter value at runtime?

Tags: python, simpy

I have been wondering whether it is possible to extract value of 'until' parameter passed
to simpy.run() method at runtime. It is probably possible to around this issue by storing this
value elsewhere, but it may be I am just curious if simpy provides such feature (in the end env has to be aware when to stop running).

I tried to print the result of: dir(env), but I have not found anything interesting there.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find [the implementation for `Environment.run()` here](https://github.com/cristiklein/simpy/blob/1f3da05e81e20ae5fec697aea538b164128d632a/src/simpy/core.py#L98-L133).

It looks like the `until` argument is converted into an `Event` with a "stop simulation" callback that is `schedule()`d.

If you really need the `until` time, you could walk `Environment._queue`, looking for something with an `Event` whose callback is `StopSimulation.callback`, but that's hardly straightforward.

You'll likely be best off just storing the "next" until time somewhere else.

If needed, maybe directly on the instance...

```
env._next_until = 123  # Hack: stash the next until time
env.run(until=env._next_until)
```